# Complex Model the Rails Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm implementing questionnaires on a site.  There are multiple questionnaires, each have sections, each section has questions. Users can fill out zero or many questionnaires.

model code below.  ERD image https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y0r3.png

What would be the "Rails Way" for storing/displaying question results while maintaining section hierarchy in the view?  I don't mind writing code, but wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious.  I've started with methods in the Question model but it doesn't take advantage of Form Helpers and the like.

```
#Simplistic view code
%h1= @user_questionnaire.questionnaire.value
- for section in @user_questionnaire.questionnaire.sections
  %h4=section.value
  %br
  - for question in section.questions
    =question.value
    =question.result(@user_questionnaire.id)
```

Any thoughts are welcome.  Thanks!
Donald

Model Code

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  has_many :user_questionnaires
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :questionnaire
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :user_questionnaire_results

  def result(uq_id)
    uqr = UserQuestionnaireResult.where(:question_id => self.id, :user_questionnaire_id => uq_id).first
    uqr.result  
  end    
end

class UserQuestionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :questionnaire
  has_many :user_questionnaire_results
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserQuestionnaireResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_questionnaire
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with your `result(uq_id)` method is that it will query DB for every result, which is slow and consty resource-wise. What you could do is to use `joins` or `includes` methods to optimize your DB access. So in your model:

```
class UserQuestionnaire
    def self.includes_questions
      includes :questionnaire => {:sections => [:questions]}
    end

    def loaded_result question
      user_questionnaire_results.to_a.find { |r| r.question_id == question.id }
    end
end
```

Then in controller:

```
@user_questionnaire = UserQuestionnaire.includes_questions.find params[:id]
```

And in view instead of `=question.result(@user_questionnaire.id)` use:

```
= @user_questionnaire.loaded_result question
```

The idea is that you load from DB all sections, questions and result togather, not each separate instance. In the same manner you may try to play with `joins` function and see if it's better for you.

Check logs or console in dev env to see which queries are executed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay of getting around to testing this out, but it turned out to be a very clean, DRY approach.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!